# Unable to read contact Android LG-D855 (LG-G3) programatically

Tags: android, android-contacts, lg

I am trying to read contact problematically, Code is working in other devices like Moto, Samsung, Huawi, but not working in LG-D855 (LG-G3).
Here is my code:

```
char lastChar = ' ';
    ArrayList<PhoneContact> phoneContacts = new ArrayList<>();
    ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID};
    String order =  ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
            + " COLLATE NOCASE ";

    String filter = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " NOT LIKE ''";
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, filter, null, order);
    PhoneContact phoneContact;
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // names comes in hand sometimes
            String name = cur.getString(1);
            String emailAddress = cur.getString(3);

            char firstChar = name.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            phoneContact = new PhoneContact(name, emailAddress);

            phoneContacts.add(phoneContact);
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }

    cur.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check phone permission to read contact because some device dont allow to read contact from third party apps.

Here is link on of Xiaomi phone which is  not able displayed conatcts in Whatsapp phone .

[enter link description here](http://webcazine.com/11724/how-to-solve-contacts-not-displayed-in-whatsapp-on-your-xiaomi-phone/)